Refrence to "..." is ambiguous
I am trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm to solve a problem for school, but I keep getting the error "Reference to distance is ambiguous".
Here is my code:
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const long MAXN = 100000, MAXM = 400000, MAXL = 50000;
const long long INF = 0x3f3f3f3f;

long N, M, L;
vector<pair<long, long> > adj[MAXN];
vector<long> Q(MAXL);

long distance[MAXN][MAXN];

void Dijkstra(long X){
    for(long i = 0; i < N; i++){
        distance[X][i] = INF;
    }
    distance[X][X] = 0;
}

int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    
    scanf("%ld %ld", &N, &M);
    
    long a, b, w;
    
    for(long i = 0; i < N; i++){
        scanf("%ld %ld %ld", &a, &b, &w);
        adj[a - 1].push_back({b - 1, w});
        adj[b - 1].push_back({a - 1, w});
    }
    
    scanf("%ld", &L);
    
    for(long i = 0; i < L; i++){
        scanf("%ld", &Q[i]);
    }
    
    for(long i = 0; i < N; i++){
        Dijkstra(i);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

The problem appears to be in the function "Dijkstra" whenever there is a refrence to the distance array.

#include <bits/stdc++.h> is a bad programming practice. I would recommend using a good c++ book

Always post complete error along with your question. See the answers in the dupe What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?. Another dupe: why is it giving an error saying " reference to max is ambiguous" in line 12 "if(k>=max)"?

Because you used using namespace std;, your distance conflicts wth std::distance. You should read Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?, and Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?.

All those global variables are also bad habits. As is the cargo cult around sync_with_stdio and cin.tie(nullptr).

@HolyBlackCat That would be the complete answer to the question, you should post it.

In short, using so-called "competition" sites to learn the basics of C++ (or any other programming language) is not a good idea. Use them as a hobby or a bit of fun when you're experienced, but not before or for other reasons.

@Lundin I'm tempted to close as a dupe of the question I linked.

@Lundin No need to repeat the answer when there are plenty of dupes. Not every question deserves a separate answer. Being a high rep user I can see that this is common enough SO c++ question.

@user12002570 Well, unlike the linked duplicate, this question actually demonstrates what problems using namespace std; might cause. Some of the supposedly "canonical" duplicates aren't good at all despite the ridiculous amount of up-voting. A question like this might be an embryo to something better, if we would leave it open. For example the whole story isn't told in the linked duplicate, one of the reasons why we can't use using namespace std; is because so many things in the std namespace have horrible names - a lot of it is designed for namespace collisions as if on purpose.

@Lundin Did you miss the other/second dupe I linked in my comment: why is it giving an error saying " reference to max is ambiguous" in line 12 "if(k>=max)"?. I'll add it in the dupe list.
